# How to avoid problematic/undefined behavior when locking NFS files on Linux?

Tags: linux, nfs, file-locking

I have used flock() and fcntl() in the past, but I've always been concerned that behavior is undefined or problematic for some older versions of Linux.

I need a solution that is compatible with older Linux-es (say, 2.6.18 or better), and NFS 3+.

Will flock() and/or fcntl() work consistently under those circumstances, or do I need to resort to open (.... O_EXCL) to guarantee atomicity?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely cannot expect `flock()` to work with NFS.  `fcntl()` with `F_SETLK` has a decent chance of working, with caveats if you have multiple uses in one process: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/locking.html

Answer (score 0):

Historically, `flock` has been available for at least a decade, and implemented by the kernel since 2.0. From the `flock man page`:

> Since kernel 2.0, flock() is implemented as a system call in its own
>   right rather than being emulated in the GNU C library as a call to
>   fcntl(2). This yields true BSD semantics: there is no interaction
>   between the types of lock placed by flock() and fcntl(2), and flock()
>   does not detect deadlock.

I think it will cover your needs, unless you are dealing with pre-2.0 kernels.